# Javascript onclick event not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onclicklistener, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

The code below is a link which when clicked will open and close an initially hidden div. It works fine other than having to click the link twice in the first instance to open it. It's not a major problem but if it can be made so that the div opens on the first click that would be great.

toggleDiv.js

```
function toggleDiv(elem, eventType, handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
    }
}

toggleDiv(window, 'load', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('myMagicLink'),
        div = document.getElementById('foo');
    toggleDiv(link, 'click', function() {
        if (!link) return true;
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "block"
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none"
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

---

index.html

```
<body>
<a id="myMagicLink" href="http://www.google.com/">My Magic Link</a>
<div id="foo">Opens a div</div>
<br>
End of page
<br>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="toggleDiv.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing this? Then again I do not see any code which 'initially hides' the said div.

Comment: @ LOSTCODER  Chrome it's a popup extension using manifest v2 so no inline javascript

Comment: This isn't what's causing it to go wrong, but your code would be easier to understand (and maintain) if `toggleDiv()` was called something like `addEventHandler()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for toggling the display value of an ASIDE tag. Switching from "none" to "inline" and back again would not work on the first click. Display was set to "none" in my CSS file.
In my script I changed "none" to "" (which seems to mean "default" as far as I understand). The following code works fine for me now.

```
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
if (x.style.display == "")
{
    x.style.display = "inline"; 
}
else
{
    x.style.display = "";   
}
```

I understood this when I saw the CSS/actual values in Firefox developer tools: "aside" is shown with CSS attributes, but an "element" is first shown with no attribute. On first click, "element" was assigned a "display" attribute set to "none".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the trouble you are having this... this works flawlessly for me in Chrome.

I did change the url of your link to reflect back to the same document, but the div `foo` is hiding and reappearing as it should.

Couple of style notes: Rather than setting `display = "block"` it is better to say `display = ""` so it can return to its default value.

In addition, I also included a preventDefault function.  Your use of `return true` would work for DOM0 style event handling, but it did not work with the `attachEvent/addEventHandler` code.  This properly keeps the link from being followed.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
function toggleDiv(elem, eventType, handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
    }
}


toggleDiv(window, 'load', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('myMagicLink'),
        div = document.getElementById('foo');
    toggleDiv(link, 'click', function(e) {
        if (!link) return cancelDefaultAction(e);

        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "block"
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none"
        }       
        return cancelDefaultAction(e);
    });
});

function cancelDefaultAction(e) {
 var evt = e ? e:window.event;
 if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
 evt.returnValue = false;
 return false;
}   

</script>


<body>
<a id="myMagicLink" href="#">My Magic Link</a>
<div id="foo">Opens a div</div>
<br>
End of page
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ jeremy I replaced with your code but still need to click the link twice initially before the div opens. This is a popup Chrome extension if that helps.

Comment: The div starts off open.  The first click hides it and the second click opens it again.  You might want to do a `<div id="foo" style="display:none">` to start it off hidden -- if that is your intended goal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it seems a bit complicated for something pretty simple, unless you have a specific design in mind; but this should work equally well:

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dane/g5jWk/6/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var toggled = false;
    function toggleDiv()
        {
           if(toggled)
             {
               document.getElementById('foo').style.display = '';
               toggled = false;            
             }       
           else
           {
               document.getElementById('foo').style.display = 'none';
               toggled = true;
           }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<a id="myMagicLink" href="http://www.google.com/" onClick='toggleDiv()'>My Magic Link</a>
<div id="foo">Opens a div</div>
<br>
End of page
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: thanks but this is a chrome extension so inline javascript won't work